# How do you draw a vertical line ever 4 hours?

Tags: pine-script

I'm working on a strategy and I need to draw a vertical line every 4 hours. How would you draw a vertical line every 4 hours on Trading view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [vline()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/EmTkvfCM-vline-Function-for-Pine-Script-v4-0/) function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) =>
    line.new(BarIndex, low - ta.tr, BarIndex, high + ta.tr, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=true)

bars_4h = 240 / f_resInMinutes()

if((bar_index % bars_4h) == 0)
    vline(bar_index, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it has a 2-hour offset, so the code above is buggy.

Comment: @Morteza can you please give an example?

Comment: Just use it in 1m timeframe for few hours. Not sure if I give an exact time, you can reproduce it, because it's dependent on time.